# Is there a more efficient way to iterate through a string until you reach a certain character?

Tags: java, string

In this method, I'm trying to go through a string of 70 characters until I reach a letter that's not an 'A' or a 'B'. Once I find a character that doesn't belong, I should return "ERR!"; I also return this statement if the string is not exactly 70 characters long.

The way I did it was by keeping track of both the total letters counted so far, and the total number of wrong letters (letters not 'A' or 'B'). Then I said that if the number of wrong letters was not 0 and if the length of the string came out to be not 70, the "ERR!" message is returned.

```
 public static String checkInput(String answers) { 
      int count = 0;
      int wrong = 0;
      String errorMessage = ""; 

      for(int i = 0; i < answers.length(); i++) {
         count++;
         if(answers.charAt(i) != 'A' && answers.charAt(i) != 'B') {
            wrong++;
         }   
      }   

      if(wrong != 0 || count != ANSWER_LENGTH) {
         errorMessage = "ERR!";
      }   
      return errorMessage;
   }
```

My code works perfectly fine, but if there is anything that can be shortened or simplified to reduce the number of lines in my program, that's what I need. Any ideas/tips are appreciated!!

Comment: A quick observation is you don't need a count variable.

You can compare the answer.length() == ANSWER_LENGTH . And do that comparison initially. Before the for loop. So that you can avoid unnecessary loop for that case.

Is there any other info on the String, like number of A's and number B's in the String?

Comment: May be String.matches("[AB]*") helps

Comment: You can check string length with [`length()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length()) and `break` out of your loop as soon as you find the first error.

Comment: @Dongqing all letters in string must be either A or B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way if there are any characters other than A or B it would immediately fails.

```
public static final String checkInput(final String answers) {
    if (answers==null || answers.length() != ANSWER_LENGTH)
        return "ERR!"; // fail fast
    if(!answer.matches("[AB]*")) 
       return "ERR!"; // fail fast
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would add a null check to Lashane's answer for robustness.

```
if (answers == null || answers.length() != 70)
```

Answer (score 1):

Number of lines (or lines of code LOC) is not very important in java, but anyway, here is shorter and faster variant:

```
public static final String checkInput(final String answers) {
    if (answers.length() != ANSWER_LENGTH)
        return "ERR!"; // fail fast
    for (int i = 0; i < answers.length(); i++)
        if (answers.charAt(i) != 'A' && answers.charAt(i) != 'B')
            return "ERR!"; // fail fast
    return "";
}
```